# What UK mushrooms will kill you?

Tags: uk, foraging, edible, mushrooms

I've recently gotten into foraging for mushrooms locally and have been happily eating [field mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus_campestris) and [giant puffballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvatia_gigantea) (these are absolutely delicious if you can find them BTW).

I was reading a foraging book the other day and it stated that there is only one truly deadly poisonous mushroom in the UK ([The Death cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_phalloides)). All the others may well make you really ill but would be unlikely to kill you, unless you eat them in large quantities.

Is this true?

Comment: "All things are poison and nothing is without poison; only the dose makes a thing not a poison." - Paracelsus (sorry :) )

Comment: Never too early for some ancient greek(?) @imsodin :)

Comment: Actually Paracelsus is a Swiss compatriot (was born like 30km from here) living during the Renaissance ;)

Comment: https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/blog/2016/10/poisonous-mushrooms/

Comment: There are a few -  John Wright fed some mildly poisonous ones to Hugh Fearnly-Whittingstall as a revenge prank (he got numb tongue) - that said John Wright is the ultimate UK based mushroom guy - he does courses even.... he has some pointers on foraging mushrooms: http://www.ediblebush.com/foraging+warnings

Comment: Webcaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orellani almost killed the author of *The Horse Whisperer*, Nicholas Evans, when he ate some in Scotland. Several people were poisoned and had to undergo dialysis, I believe Evans and a couple of other members of the party had kidney transplants as a result.

Comment: I'm reading here is that the book meant was that there is only one **common** poisonous native mushroom. The others seem quite rare, maybe I misread it.

Comment: Another guide listing a few: http://www.wildfooduk.com/mushroom-guides/#in_season (I was looking at this recently but only for identification of some in the garden)

Comment: @ChrisH, as with Separatrix, you've found a link with accurate and important information. Are you planning on turning it into an answer?

Comment: @Sue for an answer I'd like a more definitive source ideally; I lack the expertise to judge the accuracy. Also that site lists only "poisonous" and "edible", while others list "inedible" (presumably disgusting) as a separate category, so it feels a little incomplete to me. In particular the first thing I'd quote is its disclaimer which wouldn't leave me much faith in the answer

Comment: @ChrisH That's a good point, especially dealing with something this important. If you want me to delete my comment and you to delete your response, that's fine with me!

Comment: @Sue there's room for both opinions here, and some of what I've said should probably have been in my initial comment, so I don't mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am quite certain that there are more deadly mushrooms than just the one you mentioned - if only for the other members of the [Amanita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita#Toxicity) Genus, many of which are very poisonous and some plain kill you.

E.g. [Amanita Vitrosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_virosa), with the uncommonly poetic name *destroying angel* (German: Weisser Knollenblätterpilz), is just as deadly as the one you mentioned. What makes it potentially even more dangerous (or at least I was told so by several people who taught me mushroom foraging as a kid) is that it has some similarities to the [Agaricus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus) (German: Champignon), some of which are commonly collected for eating. Apparently it happens that people mix them up and get themselves killed this way.

Bottom line: Best don't touch anything from the Amanita Genus. From Wikipedia:

> Although some species of Amanita are edible, many fungi experts advise against eating a member of Amanita unless the species is known with absolute certainty. Because so many species within this genus are so deadly toxic, if a specimen is identified incorrectly, consumption may cause extreme sickness and possibly death.

2nd Bottom line: know your mushrooms. **Stick to the ones you know well** and are clearly distinguishable from poisonous members of the Fungi kingdom.

If ever in doubt, don't eat them - or **get the mushrooms tested** first: I don't know about other places, but in Switzerland in mushroom season there are designated mushroom control offices where people can bring their finds and have them looked at by a fungi expert. (See [VAPKO](http://www.vapko.ch/index.php/de/), page in German/French/Italian)

Comment: Champignon is the English word too BTW :)

Comment: @Liam hehe, good to know. I looked it up in some dictionaries and it simply translated to 'mushroom'.